# How to get first page to equal 1 everytime

Tags: php

Below I have a line of code where it states which Page a user is currently on out of the number of Total Pages.

```
<h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

So for example the line could read this:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 3 OF 3
```

Now the problem I have is that if the user is on the first page, it doesn't display the number 1. So instead of stating 1 OF 3 or 1 OF 5, it is stating 2 OF 3 or 2 OF 5.

So my question is that how can I get the first page to equal 1 OF ... when user accesses the first session (first page)?

Below is the current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 0;

    }

else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
}


$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

`$_SESSION['sessionNum']` is the total number of Sessions. So if it is 3 OF 5, then `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` is 5.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to build something like "Wizards" then in sessions you would store some data to keep track of user activity and general process, you say "if the user is in the first session ..." that's confusing, better say "if the user is in first step"

say you want to store in sessions, "user is in step 1 of 3 total steps", you would need

```
$_SESSION["user_track"] = array(
 ("current") => 1,
 ("next")=>2,
 ("total") => 3,
 ("previous") => 0
);
```

and a IF to check on every step

```
if($_SESSION["user_track"]["next"] != $GLOBAL_STEP){
 /*
  $GLOBAL_STEP , a integer you defined in the current step say its 2
  and users next step matches 2 then he/she is on the correct step
 */
}else if($_SESSION["user_track"]["next"] == $_SESSION["user_track"]["total"]){
 /*At the ending step*/
}else{
 // couldn't proceed to next step, something went wrong
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I have read your answer but I am really confused. I have never heard of Wizards before but first of all, there could be any number of sessions (in you example you have done it so that if there is 3 sessions), so how can I build an array for numerous sessions. Second of all I am confused on the IF statment as I don't know which part of my code goes into the IF statement. Is there a way if you don't mind re-writing your answer so that it matches with code so then not only I can us it, but it will also give me a better understand for future use?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

- to use the word 'page' or 'steps' instead of 'session', because 'session' is confusing with the `$_SESSION` array.
- to use a simple `GET` parameter for current page/step (e.g. `yourpage.php?step=X`), where by default the step value would be 1.